# Can I run Cypress open and cypress run at the same time?

Tags: cypress

So I want to launch tests with `cypress run`, and at the same time use `cypress open` to create/modify different tests. Will it influence my background test runs somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

Technically, you can even launch `cypress run` several times in parallel. For example, you can create 2 config files that point towards 2 different test folders, and then run `cypress run -C config_file_1 & cypress run -C config_file_2`. It will run two cypress instances at the same time.

When I was testing a test suite that was taking about 40s to perform:

- Running it 3 times back to back: **40 * 3 = 120s**
- Running it 3 times in parallel: **55s**